# Who were the Rambam's students?

Tags: history, rambam

Someone recently asked me whether the Rambam had any students. In addition to the Rambam's son and the student for whom he wrote the Moreh Nevuchim, I could think of only one other student. (רבינו פרחיה who wrote a commentary on שבת is a talmid, I think, but I would appreciate information about him too.) Does anyone have any information about other students and whether the Rambam had a yeshiva, etc.?

Comment: i thought reb ovadyo hajeir was his student too?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Sefer - [Maamar Rabbi Yosef Ben Yehuda Talmid HaRambam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21986).

Comment: I think this is the student for whom the Rambam wrote the Moreh, but if you have any info about him that would be appreciated.

Comment: @wfb It was. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Judah_of_Ceuta

Comment: or: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8853-joseph-ben-judah-ibn-aknin

Answer (score 3):

Found a brief discussion [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38376&st=&pgnum=100&hilite=):

> The Rambam was apparently not the head of a yeshiva, but instead
>   surrounded himself with a few students. Possibly, the many obligations
>   which he describes in his letter to R. Shmuel ibn Tibbon prevented him
>   [from establishing a yeshiva], or perhaps there were other reasons.
>   Either way, he taught a few important students, and studied with them
>   Talmud, the Rif, or his Mishneh Torah, each according to what his heart
>   desired... Among his students, only a few are known, such as his prime
>   disciple R. Yosef ibn Enkin (who later settled in Baghdad and Aleppo)
>   and R. Saadya son of Berakhot the Teacher.

Also found this [article](http://goo.gl/OqaaK) which discusses the importance of recently published writings of the Rambam's students for understanding the Rambam.